# VB.net COM 参照 "MSXML2" をパス "C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll" から処理しています。

Tags: vb.net, com

お世話になります。表題についてネットで検索をしてみたのですが、どうしても解決が出来ずお尋ねさせて頂きます。

以下の環境で開発をしております。

- Visual Studio 2017のVB.net
- Windows 7 (32 bit)

プロジェクトをビルドすると次の警告が出てしまいます。

> COM 参照 "MSXML2" をパス "C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll" から処理しています。'SAXXMLReader60.getSecureBaseURL' の引数のうち少なくとも 1 つをランタイム マーシャラーでマーシャリングできません。  したがってこのような引数はポインターとして渡され、アンセーフ コードの使用が必要になります。

「参照の追加」で「Microsoft XML, v6.0」に変更等などしてみたのですが、一向に警告は消えません。

MSXML2を以下の処理で使用しております。

```
Imports MSXML2

'省略
Dim ServerXML As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60()
ServerXML.open("Get", apistr, False)
ServerXML.send()
```

また以下のサイトも読みながら対応してみたのですが、当問題に関係しているのかも正直よくわかりません。

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsql/2016/11/25/howtouse_msxml2domdocument/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms753751.aspx

どのようにすれば警告が消せるのかご教示下さい。

どうぞ宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: VB.NETでは[`System.Xml`名前空間](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.xml.aspx)にて[XMLドキュメント](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/2bcctyt8.aspx)の操作をサポートしています。その機能を使わずあえてMSXMLを使用する理由は何でしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。System.Xmlを使用しない理由は特段にはありません。検索した結果、APIを用いてXMLで送受信するための機能として、MSXMLがあったので、それを特段の理由もなく用いている次第です。System.Xmlで実現できるか試してみます。

Comment: System.Xmlでも実現できる事は確認できました。質問した警告についてですが、次のサイトの8にある答えで対応いたしました。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269063/lots-of-build-warnings-when-com-objects-activeds-or-msxml2-are-referenced　　　正しい対処かはわかりませんが、いったんこれでクローズします。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

System.Xmlでも実現できる事は確認できました。
質問した警告についてですが、次のサイトの8にある答えで対応いたしました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269063

> 次のサイトの8にある答え

`8`が2017年当時に8票の回答と想定し、高評価の回答を引用翻訳します。

> I added the following key to the property group of each build configuration:

(csprojの)『ビルド構成』プロパティグループに下記のキーを追加して対応しました：

```
<ResolveComReferenceSilent>True</ResolveComReferenceSilent>
```

---

<sup>この投稿は @Tom さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/36412/#comment36374_36412)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>